# Bunyan logger.info error in Restful API

Tags: node.js, logging, bunyan

I'm working on a Restful API and I'm logging all the important steps with bunyan, including the requests. I'm having two problems with logging: 
My first problem is that when I log them, all my objects, instead of appearing like independent objects, appear in the `msg` field, like strings.

**Here is my code to log the requests:**

```
var logger = bunyan.createLogger({
    name: 'main', 
    streams: [{ 
        level: 'info', 
        path: './logs/requests.log'
    }]
});

logRequest = function(request){
    logger.info("Request started.", {id: request.id}, {method: request.method});
};
```

and when I see the request.log file it appears like this (*I've just added some tabs to make it more comfortable to see*) :

```
{
    "name": "logger",
    "hostname": "LLAS",
    "pid": 7700,
    "level": 30,
    "msg":"Request started. { id: '1428527975041:LLAS:7700:i898o4l5:10000'{ method:'post' } ",
    "time":"2015-04-08T21:19:35.055Z",
    "v":0
}
```

So my problem is that **"msg"** field, I want to see the "id" and "method" like other fields instead of a string. **I.E.** :

```
 {
        "name": "logger",
        "hostname": "LLAS",
        "pid": 7700,
        "level": 30,
        "msg":"Request started.",
        "id": '1428527975041:LLAS:7700:i898o4l5:10000',
        "method":  'post',
        "time":"2015-04-08T21:19:35.055Z",
        "v":0
 }
```

How can I solve my problem?

And my second problem is: When I do more than one log in the same file,it writes the JSON in the same line, instead of a new line, like this:

```
{"name":"logger",...,"v":0}{"name":"logger",...,"v":0}
```

Instead of this:

```
{"name":"logger",...,"v":0}
{"name":"logger",...,"v":0}
```

And I can't work later with those objects in the same line, also it is hard to read and mantain in that way.

Anyone know why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My first problem is that when I log them, all my objects, instead of
>   appearing like independent objects, appear in the "msg" field, like
>   strings.

That's because you are passing more than one object. You can only pass one object as the first parameter for logging, all other parameters will be considered as `msg`. From the [bunyan source code](https://github.com/trentm/node-bunyan/blob/master/lib/bunyan.js#L975):

```
/**
 * The functions below log a record at a specific level.
 *
 * Usages:
 *    log.<level>()  -> boolean is-trace-enabled
 *    log.<level>(<Error> err, [<string> msg, ...])
 *    log.<level>(<string> msg, ...)
 *    log.<level>(<object> fields, <string> msg, ...)
 *
 * where <level> is the lowercase version of the log level. E.g.:
 *
 *    log.info()
 * ....
 */
```

So if you pass all your parameters in one object, it will work properly:

```
var request = { id: "abc", method: "GET" }; // dummy request object
logger.info({id: request.id, method: request.method}, "Request started.");
```

The result is (pretty printed):

```
{
  "name": "main",
  "hostname": "Victors-MacBook-Pro.local",
  "pid": 2848,
  "level": 30,
  "id": "abc",
  "method": "GET",
  "msg": "Request started.",
  "time": "2015-04-08T23:25:37.967Z",
  "v": 0
}
```

> And my second problem is: When I do more than one log in the same
>   file,it writes the JSON in the same line, instead of a new line.

Are you on Windows? If you are, maybe the problem is that bunyan may be using the UNIX style carriage return (`\n`) and not the Windows style (`\r\n`). Try using a text editor that supports UNIX style carriage returns (like notepad++ or sublime text, for example).

Comment: I'm using Windows temporally but I'll try it in sublime, Thanks for your explanation! It worked for me.